# What does mean the term Feature Band applied to the MSI installer for Windows?

Tags: .net-core, windows-installer

Recently I have been reading the article by Microsoft [What's new in .NET Core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0)
and in its part

> **.NET Core SDK Windows Installer**

> The MSI installer for Windows has changed starting with .NET Core 3.0. The SDK installers will now upgrade SDK `feature-band` releases in place. `Feature bands` are defined
> in the hundreds groups in the patch section of the version number. For
> example, 3.0.101 and 3.0.201 are versions in two different `feature bands` while 3.0.101 and 3.0.199 are in the same `feature band`. And,
> when .NET Core SDK 3.0.101 is installed, .NET Core SDK 3.0.100 will be
> removed from the machine if it exists. When .NET Core SDK 3.0.200 is
> installed on the same machine, .NET Core SDK 3.0.101 won't be removed.

I have found for the first time the term `feature band`. Could someone please explain what exactly this term means in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means when they change the third version number by the hundreds they also change the UpgradeCode to allow it to install side by side.

Comment: But why? What is the value in doing this? It also doesn't actually answer the quesion of what a "feature band" is.

Comment: It was a made up term from that team.  Think Visual STudio... major versions like 2013, 2015 can be installed side by side without upgrading each other.  In the .NET Core 3.x family they were saying this was the behavior every 100 releases.  3.101 would upgrade 3.100 and 3.200 would be installed side by side and upgraded by 3.201.  They only do this for the SDK these days.  The runtime every version is installed side by side.